# Sortable unique ids for Android chat messages

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, chat, unique-key

I am developing an android chat application where i need unique chat message ids which should be sortable (in older to recent order) and will be saved in sqlite db.

As of now I have taken integer auto-increment key of Sqlite which is functioning but not sure if this is correct way of doing .
I am new to this domain and have little idea.I ask sorry if my question seems very naive and trivial to you guys .

Your suggestions may lead me to make my product efficient and simpler .

Comment: I did exactly this last week - though not on SQLite, I used Firebase, but the unique Id I used was formed of both the display name of the chat message poster plus a time stamp, concatenated in one field, then sorted via a comparator in time order.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use time in millisecond or time in nanosecond for the message id. If your app is 2 way messaging system, You can easy sort the messages in chronological order that they have sent from the users. If you use the id with auto increment, you'll end up having time conflict as the other users messages may get delayed over the network.

```
System.nanoTime()
```

Comment: message ids solely based on time (at one user) may create a problem to those messages which are sent to other guy (in different time zone) and these ids would not be useful for other guy .

Comment: How about using UTC?

Answer (score 0):

I would use IDs issued by the server. The server may generate them as an auto-increment key in a database or by incrementing some other counter, say per-conversation.